# Can't figure out how to automatically set MariaDB root password without user intervention

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, bourne-shell

I'm making a script that installs MariaDB, and I'd like to set a root password. I've got the following in said script:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

echo mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0/root_password password tmpsetup | debconf-set-selections
echo mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0/root_password_again password tmpsetup | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

This doesn't seem to work, as I can't log into the root account with the "tmpsetup" password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same on Zesty w/ mariadb-server-10.1.  Can't figure out the secret sauce to make this work.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same on Xenial w/ mariadb-server-10.0. Can't figure out the secret sauce to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try instead with

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

echo mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server/root_password password tmpsetup | debconf-set-selections
echo mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server/root_password_again password tmpsetup | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y mariadb-server
```

That way the changes will be applied also to mariadb-server meta-package, and not only for the specific version.

Comment: That didn't work. And I don't think that's correct, because the other MariaDB debconf entries (made by the installer) show up as `mariadb-server-10.0`.